# lower bound on the minimum singular value of $\underline{\sigma} (A+B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

what can we say about the lower bound on $\underline{\sigma}(A+B)$?

Can we say the following?

$\underline{\sigma}(A+B)>\underline{\sigma}(A)+\bar{\sigma}(B)$,

where $\underline{\sigma}$ denotes the minimum singular value and $\bar{\sigma}$ the maximum singular value.

I actually look for the case where $A=I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can't. To construct a simple counterexample, consider $A$ and $B$ scalars and note that a singular value of a scalar is its absolute value.

We can say however that 
$$
|\underline{\sigma}(A+B)-\underline{\sigma}(A)|\leq\overline{\sigma}(B),
$$
which is a standard perturbation result for singular values. This gives
$$
-\overline{\sigma}(B)\leq\underline{\sigma}(A+B)-\underline{\sigma}(A)\leq\overline{\sigma}(B)
$$
and hence
$$
\underline{\sigma}(A+B)\geq\underline{\sigma}(A)\color{red}{-}\overline{\sigma}(B)
$$
and
$$
\underline{\sigma}(A+B)\color{red}{\leq}\underline{\sigma}(A)+\overline{\sigma}(B).
$$