# Bound quotient of maximal and minimal singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symplectic-geometry, singular-values, symplectic-linear-algebra

I am working on a problem where the following quantity emerges:
$$
\frac{\sigma_{\text{max}}(J-M)}{\sigma_{\text{min}}(J+M)}
$$
where $J$ is the canonical symplectic matrix, $M^T=M$ and $M$ is positive semi-definite.

I want to bound from above this quantity, which seems to be specific enough to try to get a good bound.

For the moment I have tried the simple approach that follows
$$
\frac{\sigma_{\text{max}}(J-M)}{\sigma_{\text{min}}(J+M)}\leq \frac{1+\|M\|_2}{1-\|M\|_2}
$$
where the last bound comes from an estimate in [lower bound on the minimum singular value of $\underline{\sigma} (A+B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548418/lower-bound-on-the-minimum-singular-value-of-underline-sigma-ab) .
Do you see a better solution?

Comment: Why did you write it this way?  From what I see, you're asking for the condition number of $(J+M)$ since negation and transposition don't change singular values

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about this. Do you know of any results about the condition number of matrices structured in this way?

Answer (score 1):

There is a result from Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* that might be helpful here:

> **Theorem VI.2.3:** Let $A$ be Hermitian, and $B$ skew-Hermitian.  Let their eigenvalues be arranged so that
> $$
> |\alpha_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\alpha_n| \quad \text{and} \quad |\beta_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\beta_n|
> $$
> Let $T = A + B$, and let $s_j$ be the singular values of $T$.  Then the following majorization relations are satisfied:
> $$
> \{|\alpha_j + \beta_{n - j+1}|^2\}_j \prec \{s_j^2\}_j\\
> \left\{\frac 12(s_j^2 + s_{n - j + 1}^2) \right\}_j \prec \{|\alpha_j + \beta_{j}|^2\}_j
> $$

Majorization is explained on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization). For our case, we note that $J$ is skew-symmetric with eigenvalues $\pm i$. With the second majorization condition, we have
$$
\frac 12 \left(\sigma_{\max}^2([-M] + J) + \sigma_{\min}^2([-M] + J)\right) \leq 1 + \|M\|_2^2 \implies
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_{\max}^2(J-M) &\leq 2(1 + \sigma_{\max}^2(M)) - (1 + \sigma_{\min}^2(M))
\\ & = 1 + \left[2 \sigma_{\max}^2(M)\ - \sigma_\min^2(J - M)\right],
\end{align}
which might yield a tighter upper bound on the numerator.

Comment: Thank you. I do not understand the last equality you write. How does $\sigma_{min}^2(J-M)$ come into the equation?